# How the change attributes of UI elements with JavaScript in Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I know there is this server side method called renderUI, but it makes updating the UI extremely slow in some cases, so I am now relying on the JavaScript.

My problem is a follows. I would like to update the title attribute of material_card from shinymaterial package. I would like to see the title to change, every time I select an alternative from a separate dropdown menu.

So far my list of UI components contain tags$script() object, which is supposed to observe the changes in the selectInput (goes with id "dropdown").

My code looks as follows:

```
library(shinymaterial)
library(shiny)

ui <- material_page(

    titlePanel("Soon to be working JavaScript example!"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput(
                "dropdown",
                "Dropdown menu",
                c('Hat','Shoes','Jacket')),
                tags$script('
              $(document).on("shiny:inputchanged", function(event) {
                if (event.name === "dropdown") {
                    if(input.dropdown === "Jacket") {
                  //Even this alert is not working, possibly because input.name is not recognized. :(
                  alert("You chose Jacket, now the material card title will be changed to: Jacket selected");
                  //What am I supposed to put here to update the material_card title?
                    } else {
                  //...and here as well...
                }
              });'
            ),
            material_card(
                depth=5,
                title = 'This value needs to be changed according what was chosen in the dropdown menu!')
        ),
        mainPanel(
           h5('Nothing here!')
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    #The server is empty, as it should. :)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I managed to get the alert working without the if(input.dropdown === "Jacket") validation, but this validation is not working: Most likely input.dropdown is not even recognized, although it works nicely with conditional panel.

Furthermore, I am even more lost with the logic: How should I actually use JavaScript to update the material_card title, after the change in selectInput (dropdown) value has been observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shinymaterial)
library(shiny)

ui <- material_page(
  
  titlePanel("Soon to be working JavaScript example!"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "dropdown",
        "Dropdown menu",
        c('Hat','Shoes','Jacket')),
      tags$script(HTML('
              $(document).on("shiny:inputchanged", function(event) {
                if (event.name === "dropdown") {
                  if(event.value === "Jacket") {
                    alert("You chose Jacket, now the material card title will be changed to: Jacket selected");
                    $("#mycard>span.card-title").html("Here is the new card title");
                  } else {
                  //...and here as well...
                  }
                }
              });')
      ),
      material_card(
        depth=5,
        title = 'This value needs to be changed according what was chosen in the dropdown menu!',
        id = "mycard"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h5('Nothing here!')
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input,output){})
```

Comment: This solution is very good indeed, but what if I wanted to change the title something else than "You chose Jacket..." when some other option than "Jacket" was chosen?

Comment: @Aku-VilleLehtimäki `$("#mycard>span.card-title").html("You chose " + event.value + ".");`

Answer (score 2):

A shiny UI-only solution:

```
library(shinymaterial)
library(shiny)

dropdownChoices <- c('Hat','Shoes','Jacket')

ui <- material_page(
  
  titlePanel("Soon to be working JavaScript example!"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "dropdown",
        "Dropdown menu",
        dropdownChoices),
      material_card(
        depth = 5,
        title = lapply(dropdownChoices, function(i){
          conditionalPanel(sprintf('input.dropdown == "%s"', i), i)
        })
      )),
    mainPanel(
      h5('Nothing here!')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is a very simple and elegant, working solution! This is the way this should be implemented rather than using JavaScript. Thank you. (I know, saying "thank you" should be avoided in the comments, but I thank you anyway.)